# Reorganizing a list of lists

Tags: haskell

How to solve this problem?

The problem is to reorder the list-of-lists of doubles:

```
[ [a, b, c],  [aa, bb, cc] ]
```

into this:

```
[ [a, aa],   [b, bb],  [c, cc] ]
```

After poking about I came up with the following (a function that increasingly diggs deeper and deeper into sublists, taking their `head` and joining them together):

```
organize xs = organize' xs head
--recursive function (type stolen from ghci)
organize':: [[a]] -> ([a] -> b) -> [b]
organize' [] f = []
organize' xs f = (map f xs)++(organize' xs (f . tail)
```

This doesn't work too good (which I thought it did) - in my joy of success I completely missed the error:

```
 Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: That doesn't compile nor work too well, it seems. Also, can you explain better what you actually want to achieve? This looks like zipping to me.

Comment: By the description of the problem, you're probably looking for `transpose` from `Data.List`. This code doesn't work really well, because in the recursive call of `organize'`, the `xs` doesn't get any smaller; after enough recursive calls, your `f` argument basically returns empty list (it looks like `tail . tail . tail . tail ...`) and then you attempt to take head of that - which is going to make your algorithm fail.

Comment: D'oh wait something is wrong... Oh WOW i completely missed the `Exception: Prelude.head: empty list` part!

Comment: @Vitus I could kiss you! Transpose works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mention of "doubles" implies that you want a list of 2-tuples (ie, "doubles"), rather than a list of 2-element lists. (Or perhaps this wording was particular to my Function Programming 101 lecturer!)

In which case, `zip` does exactly this:

```
zip [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] = [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

If you *do* need a list of 2-element lists (instead of tuples), you can use zipWith:

```
organize [xs,ys] = zipWith (\x y -> [x,y]) xs ys
```

Or are you looking for something that will work with any number of lists? In that case (as others have commented) `transpose` from Data.List is what you're after:

```
transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Comment: `zipWith` can be quite nicely generalized with `Applicative` instance for `ZipList`s (defined as `newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }`. For example, zipping 4 lists: `(\a b c d -> [a,b,c,d]) <$> ZipList [1,2,3] <*> ZipList [4,5,6] <*> ZipList [7,8,9] <*> ZipList [10,11,12]`.